# Parse Server on Heroku Running on Web Worker Dynos

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-server, dyno

I am running a parse server on a heroku web dyno. I need to run a long requests on a worker dyno. Do I need to run two parse servers, one for web and one for the worker dyno?

How would one go about running worker dynos when working with parse? I see an [example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/asynchronous-web-worker-model-using-rabbitmq-in-node) of a nodejs worker, but not sure if it applies to a parse server.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? I've been trying to figure out how to scale parse server on heroku as well. The concepts of cloud functions and heroku workers do not seem to work well together because calling a cloud function from a worker will still put all the load on the web dyno hosting the cloud function. I'd love to keep all of my cloud functions centralized because that was the advantage of using parse in the first place. Curious if you've taken a different approach.